# Is there any API let freetype load part of strokes?

Tags: freetype2

Is there any API let freetype load part of strokes? for example, letter "A" just load first two strokes, ouput "^"

Comment: I found that outline->n_contours seems to be the count of strokes. But it's generated after called FT_Load_Glyph,with glyph->bitmap.buffer filled. I want to change outline->n_contours to whatever I want and then generate right bitmap data.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as the font files don't store the characters as strokes. It is a complete vector format that usually defines geometry to be filled and the geometry to be culled.